# If pip install - r requirements.txt gets interrupted, will the already-installed packages get deleted?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

While in the virtual environment, if `pip install -r requirements.txt` gets interrupted, will the packages that have been already installed get deleted?

I use the

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see from the snapshot, I have installed `openstacksdk`, `Pillow`, `pycparser`, when I install the `PyMYSQL` I get the interrupt.

but in my `venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` there is none of `openstacksdk`, `Pillow`, `pycparser`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

If it did not delete them, where did the packages get installed?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look of the `pip` install steps.

the packages you see in the `site-packages` is the wheels.

there are main two steps of pip install packages:

1. Collecting packages.
2. Build wheels for collected packages.

After Built wheels, then there are packages in the `site-packages`. 
your pip install interrupted in the first step, so there did not reach the second step.